# How to package jQuery function(s) into a custom function or variable?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#mydiv").hover(function() {
    $(".class").stop(true, true).fadeIn(100);
}, function() {
    $(".class").stop(true, true).fadeOut(100);
});
```

Suppose I have a snippet like something above. I have a lot similar hover functions need to be bound. How can I write a custom function to achieve this?

Something like:

```
$("#mydiv").myHover(".class", 100);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would write what's known as a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.myHover = function(s, d){
    return this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this), $selected = $(s);
        $this.hover(function(){
            $selected.stop(true, true).fadeIn(d);
        }, function(){
            $selected.stop(true, true).fadeOut(d);
        })
    });
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4seeahy6/)

You can learn all about writing them yourself here: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/

Comment: yes, PLUGIN! I do not know how to ask this question. The keyword PLUGIN save me! Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you're saved (: